# <font size=...> tag doesn't work in Text.text

Tags: html, qt, qml, qtquick2

My code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    Text {
        text: '
            <font size="100">Large</font>
            <font size="50">Medium</font>
            <font size="10">Small</font>
            '
    }
}
```

All 3 words are displayed with the same size. But [the supported HTML subset](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) is documented to include `<font size=...>`.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Im not familiar with qt but maybe you forgot the unit 'px' and the hyphen '-'

```
<font-size="100px">Large</font>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want if you use CSS styles and the property `Text.RichText`.

Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    Text {
        text: "<span style='font-size:120px;'>Large</span>"; textFormat: Text.RichText
    }
}
```

**Answer updated to add more info.**

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html), `Text.StyledText` is an optimized format supporting some basic text styling markup.

The documentation gives you some examples, like

```
<font color="color_name" size="1-7"></font>
```

So, if you want to use `<font size>`, the maximum value is 7.

You can test the behaviour using the following example. Using a size greater than 7 has no effect and the font keeps the size 7.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

        Text {
            y: 0
            textFormat: Text.RichText
            text: "<font size=1>Large</font>";
        }

        Text {
            y: 30
            textFormat: Text.RichText
            text: "<font size=7>Large</font>";
        }

        Text {
            y: 90
            textFormat: Text.RichText
            text: "<font size=10>Large</font>";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Text {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    textFormat: Text.RichText
    text: '
        <span style="font-size:100px;">Large</span>
        <span style="font-size:50px;">Medium</span>
        <span style="font-size:10px;">Small</span>
        '
}
```

Comment: Same answer than me.

Comment: yeh I guess we posted at the same time. see time stamp ;)

Comment: All in all, support seems to be pretty messed up, some tags work, others don't, other work sometimes or in unexpected ways.

Comment: @luffy Well, you are 30 seconds in the future and I live in the past, hehe. BTW, I've updated my answer.